# Intel server motherboard S1200V3RPS diagostic LED displays unlisted POST code

Tags: boot, motherboard, post, diagnostic

After some initial hiccups, I was able to get the Intel motherboard to at least power up. Now it does not start the boot process. I tried to understand the LED displays which explain problems encountered during Power-On-Self-Test(POST). I get the following code: 00101011. That is Amber LED No. 5 is on and so are Green LEDs no. 0, 1 and 3.  However, the mother board product technical specification document, does not list an explanation for this code. Need to know what is wrong with the motherboard or which component is faulty. To make sure that I was not getting the bits wrong, I tried to boot without the RAM and the diagnostic LED did show the applicable POST code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely a RAM problem as that code (2B in hex) falls into the MRC ([Memory Reference Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_Reference_Code)) range.

> George Chen, a research and development (R&D) director at ASUS, described [MRC]in 2007 as follows:
>
> "The MRC is part of reference BIOS code, which relates to memory initialisation in the BIOS. It includes information about memory settings, frequency, timing, driving and detailed operations of the memory controller."

Assuming you have more than one stick, try one at a time. If you don't, try another known-good compatible stick from someplace.

If you manage to get it running at all, ensure you update the BIOS, SDR, FRU, etc. firmware packages ASAP, and then try all your RAM again.

If you can't get it running on one known-good, known-compatible stick (and all other factors are considered OK), then the board is most likely faulty and needs to be replaced.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. You have most likely identified the problem. I checked the Intel site for approved RAM for the motherboard and ALL the ones I have or have on the board are not on the list!  I will get some new ones and try them out. Also, are there any specific MRC process codes for more detail diagnosis? I see that there are some  "MRC Fatal Error Codes" E8 - EF but these are not around 2B.